# Creating Unique Express Routes That Match Angular Router Paths

Tags: angular, express

I have a series of routes defined inside of my Express `app` that map to a set of developer defined routes that we use on our application backend. For example:

```
/session
/login
/logoff
/oauth
```

Currently, if a user visits our website and has a current, active session, they are taken directly to whichever path they have specified, i.e. https://website.com/users.

The above `/users` path however is managed by the Angular Router and once our app loads, the router takes over and sends the user there.

However, if the user were to send a request for the above URL and they did *not* have an active session, they would need to login and then our app would send them to the homepage, i.e., https://website.com.

I'd like to create a unique Express route that only matches the route that the user entered and save that as a cookie to then retrieve and use the Angular Router to send them there (`router.navigateByUrl(cookieValue)`).

Because all other requests go through the server: `/favicon`, `/navigation.min.css`, how can I create a unique entry point so that only the original path is handled?

I have tried to create custom middleware that I can place in different sections of my app, but I still get invalid paths. Setting a global variable seemed like an okay idea to monitor if the original path had already been retrieved but I was wondering if a more elegant approach existed.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Single Page Application or is it a Server Side rendered application? I'm a little confused in which part of your setup is supposed to be doing what.

Comment: @Chris It's a hybrid. We have some routes defined as part of the Exress app, but most of our backend is handled by a separate .NET microservice. I'd like to set the cookie in the Express backend and then retrieve that cookie once our SPA loads.